# Python AttributeError: 'NoneType'

Tags: python, typeerror, callable, nonetype

I am doing some code for a flash Card quiz, however when I am running the program it says `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` in this line:

```
letter = print("Enter letter of your choice (A B C): ").upper()
```

Comment: my code is way to long to fit as a comment what should i do?

Comment: it says this is the wrong line of code... letter = print("Enter letter of your choice (A B C): ").upper()

Comment: @Red Alert here is the line of code thanks

Comment: The line you show won't generate the error you refer to (though it will generate a different error). Can you paste the whole error message, with the full traceback?

Answer (score 3):

`print` is used for printing text, not for text inputs.

To make a text input, use `input` (or `raw_input` if you use Python 2):

```
letter = input("Enter letter of your choice (A B C): ").upper()
```

Comment: thanks ive changed it to input. now it is saying...UnboundLocalError: local variable 'input' referenced before assignment

Comment: Do you have any variable named `input` in your code? If yes, rename it, there is a name conflict with the builtin `input` function.

Comment: ill take a quick look now...

Comment: at the start of the program i put "input = raw_input"

Answer (score 0):

I think your try to assign the output of 'print' to a variable causes the error.